# Iterate and modify c++ priority queue

Tags: c++, boost, priority-queue

I want a priority queue where I can iterate and modify. In other words, non-constant iterator.

It seems that the 
`std::priority_queue<T>` does not support changing values of keys to protect corruption of the structure.

I found `boost::heap::prioity_queue` to support mutability of keys of **priority_queue** / modification of values with update functions to maintain invariant of data structure.

boost also supports iterators, yet they are const iterators and do not allow change.

Comment: I highly recommend not doing this, as it's _very_ easy for someone else to alter your code, make a mistake, and invalidate the queue guarantees, causing your code to behave randomly. (Such as, popping the minimum and getting a different element instead).

Comment: I wonder how boost allows the modifications of values, that would be _very_ complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard has functions to help maintain a heap, [`make_heap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/make_heap), [`push_heap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/push_heap) and [`pop_heap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/pop_heap). Combine those with `std::vector` or another random access container, and it is not much work to maintain a heap which you can iterate over.

Example:

```
std::vector<int> heap = {1,3,5,7,9};
std::make_heap(heap.begin(), heap.end());

// add an element
heap.push_back(4);
std::push_heap(heap.begin(), heap.end());

// remove an element
std::pop_heap(heap.begin(), heap.end());
heap.pop_back();

// multiply each element by 2
for (auto & i : heap)
    i *= 2;
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/Fj15iu)

Also note that all the heap functions have an optional parameter for a comparator so that you can control the ordering of your heap.

Comment: He wants to change elements besides the one at the top/front.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: It's a vector. He can do that. Perhaps I should make that clear, but I thought it was pretty obvious.

Comment: No, that would invalidate the priority queue. Hence going with Boost. Your example is contrived to avoid this by modifying every element in a particular way that preserves the ordering.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: I'm not sure what your point is. The OP wants to modify values in the priority queue. It is of course up to him to do that in such a way that does not invalidate the priority queue. I am simply providing him with information about the functions which will help him maintain the priority queue, the rest is up to him. My example was, of course, intentionally contrived to preserve the ordering.  It was simply a demonstration of the tools provided by the standard library.